# Accelerate number the closer that it reaches its max

Tags: javascript, animation, math

I'm trying to simulate the speed of a progress bar. The progress bar displays the current progress in percentages (0-100). What I am trying to achieve is a function/modifier that takes will modify the actual progress, to have it slow in the beginning and faster toward the end (as it reaches a 100%)

So for example, if the actual progress is 5% lets say our modifier would modify it to 6%, and when progress reaches 20% lets say our modifier modifies it to 35% and at 60% our modifier reports 80%....till it reaches a 100

So, its barely modifying in the beginning but steadily increasing in velocity toward the end...

I'm not sure how to approach this, I cannot tween because I don't have a time frame I can tween against. I imagine I'd have to apply a mathematical function that would modify the value on the go. The following does not work, but I'm adding it here just to illustrate my point:

```js
console.clear()
let updated = 0;
for(i=0; i <= 100; i++){
 updated = (1 - Math.pow(i/101,2))
 console.log(i + updated)
}
```

I appreciate any direction about how to approach this. Thank you

Comment: If 20 is 35 and 60 is 80 and 100 is 100, you're essentially slowing the progress bar. You probably want the opposite, where 20 is 10, 60 is 45, 90 is 85.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways.

```js
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  if (i <= 100) {
    updated = i * (Math.log10(i) / 2);
    
    document.getElementById("bar1").style.width = i + "%";
    
    document.getElementById("bar2").style.width = (i * (Math.log10(i) / 2)) + "%";
    
    document.getElementById("bar3").style.width = (i * i * i / 10000) + "%";
  i++;
}
}, 50)
```

```css
.container {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 50vw;
}

.bar {
  background: #faa;
  height: 1em;
  width: 0%;
  border-top: thin solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="bar1" class="bar">Linear</div>
  <div id="bar2" class="bar"></div>
  <div id="bar3" class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tweening functions are easier if you move between values of 0.0 and 1.0. This will allow for code similar to your's.

For example:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 1; i += .1) {
    console.log((i ** 2 *100).toFixed(2))
}
```

Accelerates quite quickly. Since `0 ** n` is always `0` and `1 ** n` is alway `1` you can freely pick exponents to change your speed while still keeping values between 0 and 1. :

> 0.00
>   1.00
>   4.00
>   9.00
>   16.00
>   25.00
>   36.00
>   49.00
>   64.00
>   81.00
>   100.00

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have an `f` `function` and you have a `t` repeat time in milliseconds, that is, the progress bar will do a step on every `t`. You can work like this:

```
var intervalID = setTimeout(f, t);
```

Now, let's think about how `f` looks like. If we want the progress bar to be slow at the beginning, but quicker at the end, then we need a function which is monotonously increasing in a steeper manner than a linear function. A linear complexity looks like this:

```
l(x) = aX + b
```

Its derivative is

```
l'(x) = a
```

which is a constant. We need a function which is increasing faster. Let's look at this function:

```
f(x) = x^2

f'(x) = 2x
```

So this will be good for you

```
function f() {
    var result = x * x;
    //Set progress bar to Math.min(result, 100)
    if (result >= 100) clearInterval(intervalID);
}
```